# Knockout JS table hilight

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, each

I'm trying to add alternating colors in table using jQuery. Problem is that I am using Knockout and when each do the style is applied to all tr. My problem is here: http://jsfiddle.net/PUc3J/2/

```
$(function(){
    $(".tk-table tbody tr")
        .each(function(i){
            if(i % 2 == 0){
                $(this).addClass('hilight');
            }
        })
});
```

thx

Comment: Your HTML markup is **invalid**. You haven't properly closed your `table` and `tr`. If you fix it, it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/VUSFB/

Comment: Sorry, was on when typed. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use **CSS alone** to accomplish the alternate table row color, as long as you are not concerned about supporting Internet Explorer 8 or lower.

http://jsfiddle.net/GJw7R/

```
.tk-table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #eaeded;
}
```

references:
 1. http://davidwalsh.name/css-tables-css3-alternate-row-colors
 2. [Twitter Bootstrap tables](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#tables)
 3. [Can I use - CSS3 selectors](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)

---

Alternatively, you could avoid resorting to jQuery and just use the
**[css binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html)** in **Knockout**.

http://jsfiddle.net/9UDkg/

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: data">
    <tr data-bind="css: $index() % 2 === 0 ? 'hilight' : ''">
        <td><p data-bind="text: online"></p></td>
        <td><p data-bind="text: name"></p></td>
        <td><p data-bind="text: email"></p></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

...or...

http://jsfiddle.net/ZDDrT/

```
<tr data-bind="css: {'hilight': $index() % 2 === 0}">
```

Answer (score 2):

See updated fiddle, i fixed your HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/tkirda/PUc3J/3/

Also, there is simpler way to find alternate rows:

```
$(".tk-table tr:odd").addClass('hilight');
```

Comment: The problem with that jQuery will be that when knockout clears the table because of the observable being changed, the styling will get lost because the DOM elements gets reconstructed. mg1075s pure CSS solution or using bindings is the correct approach. Edit: In general, whenever you want to use jQuery in a KO app, you'll want to wrap the calls in bindings, so that jQuery gets called when KO changes the DOM.